# UIButton doesn't adapt to your titleLabel in Swift

Tags: swift, uibutton, autolayout, constraints

I have a problem with the height of TitleLabel because the button is not adapted to this.
The buttons look like:

[image]

The TitleLabel leaves the buttons.

I test the buttons assigning a large height and these look good but the height is fixed and does not adjust every TitleLabel, how can i do it?
I think I must calculate the height of the buttons depending on the height of the TitleLabel but i don't know How?

Comment: The problem is that those are not buttons. A button is a small thing with a small (one-line) title. It looks like what you want is a UILabel.

Comment: If you want to make a clickable control then why don't you use a `UITableView` here ? And Yes You can still calculate the string height with in specific width, then need to add some top bottom left right padding and you can set the resulted frame to button Or you can take help of **Autolayout**.

Comment: when my text is small it looks good but when the text is long looks bad, I need to use buttons because I'm using radio buttons, i want to show questions and alternatives, the alternatives being those that are in the radio button with a height not fixed, is it possible to do this with buttons?  getting height of TitleLabel?

Comment: TheTiger: I have a function that calculates the height with a specific width but Iphones have different widths, how do i handling that? what width do I give you?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do but try tweaking the button constraints in autolayout to get the layout to expand as desired maybe? 
InterfaceBuilder [Button selected] -> Utilities (right column) -> Size inspector
scroll down to content hugging / compression resistance. Also, you can go in attribute inspector and change settings for linebreakmode (wrap) edge on content - and scaling choice.

I'd invite you to consider alternative though:
instead of assigning to buttons try fitting the text inside UILabel elements. You can then place radio buttons **next** to the UILabels (just make sure that the label content and the buttons assigned to them are linked properly.

UILabels will hold well to constraint + you can set the minimum font size for the text in the attribute inspector (so that more text gets displayed) linking the buttons to the various options.